# Can not find association by name using Shopware 6 extension

Tags: javascript, php, associations, shopware6

Shopware 6 plugin adds a custom entity and associate it via a OneToMany association with an existing entity. So we should be able to use tags for property options.

Definition:

```
        $query = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wed_property_group_option_tag` (
    `option_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
    `tag_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`, `tag_id`), 
    CONSTRAINT `fk.wed_property_group_option_tag.tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk.wed_property_group_option_tag.option_id` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `property_group_option` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SQL;
```

```
namespace Wed\Core\System\Tag;

class TagDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'tag_id';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('option_id', 'optionId', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('option', 'option_id', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class, 'id'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Wed\Core\Content\Property\Aggregate\PropertyGroupOption;

class PropertyGroupOptionDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'option_id';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            new OneToManyAssociationField('tags', FooDefinition::class, 'option_id')
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Wed\Core\Content\Property\Aggregate\PropertyGroupOption;

class WedPropertyGroupOptionTagDefinition extends MappingEntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'wed_property_group_option_tag';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new FkField('option_id', 'optionId', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('tag_id', 'tagId', TagDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('option', 'option_id', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class, 'id', false),

            new ManyToOneAssociationField('tag', 'tag_id', TagDefinition::class, 'id', false),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
namespace Wed\Extension\Content\Property\Aggregate\PropertyGroupOption;

class PropertyGroupOptionExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new ManyToManyAssociationField('myTags', TagDefinition::class, WedPropertyGroupOptionTagDefinition::class, 'option_id', 'tag_id'),
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Administration JS:

```
Shopware.Component.override('sw-property-option-detail', {
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    template,

    data: function () {
        return {
            option: undefined
        }
    },

    computed: {
        repository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('wed_property_group_option_tag');
        },
        criteria() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addAssociation('myTags');

            return criteria;
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.repository = this.repositoryFactory.create('wed_property_group_option_tag');

        this.repository.search(this.criteria, Shopware.Context.api)
            .then(option => {
                this.option = option;
            });
    }
});
```

Option detail page doesn't load, I have these error in console:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"status\":\"500\",\"code\":\"FRAMEWORK__ASSOCIATION_NOT_FOUND\",\"title\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"detail\":\"Can not find association by name myTags\",\"meta\":{\"parameters\":{\"association\":\"myTags\"}}}]}"
```

Do someone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the `myTags` association to `property_group_option` but you're creating the repository for `wed_property_group_option_tag`. There's no association `myTags` on `wed_property_group_option_tag`.

```js
Shopware.Component.override('sw-property-option-detail', {
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    template,

    data() {
        return {
            options: []
        }
    },

    computed: {
        repository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('property_group_option');
        },
        criteria() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addAssociation('myTags.tag');

            return criteria;
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.repository.search(this.criteria, Shopware.Context.api)
            .then(result => {
                this.options = result;

                this.options.forEach((option) => {
                    console.log(option.extensions.myTags);
                });
            });
    }
});
```